# Opening a solution from TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project in Visual studios 2013. I was trying to figure out how to do something and was recommended to look at another project on TFS that does something similar. When I got latest version of this other project, I found out it was made in VS2010. It migrated it to VS2013, and locked the file to me. I undid the changes because I don't want to modify this other program. I was unable to find a way to open that file without it trying to lock the file to me with migrating to VS2013. 
As an attempted solution, I copied the file elsewhere on my computer and tried opening it without connecting to TFS. I assumed this would allow it to migrate to 2013 without updating the database. It still had issues and gave me this error: `Solution file '%s' cannot be migrated because the solution cannot be checked out from source code control. To migrate the solution, make sure the solution file can be checked out and re-open it.`

How can I open this solution without updating the TFS solution and locking the file to myself?

Answer (score 32):

I just ran into this same problem. I checked the permissions on the solution files I was trying to open and saw that it was set to 'read-only'. I deselected read-only and the solution opened.

Comment: thanks! I *almost* figured this out myself but then I thought 'nah that won't work' - then after yelling at the computer for a minute I found this and it did work :-)

Answer (score 1):

If everyone else is using VS2010 with Service Pack 1, then upgrading the solution isn't a problem. People will still be able to open it in VS2010 SP1, even if you check it in. See the [Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747)  notes on MSDN for specific things to watch for.

Alternatively, after checking the files out but before opening the .sln file, create a copy of it in the same folder calling it MyProject2013.sln (for example). Add this new solution to source control using Source Control Explorer and then open it, letting Visual Studio upgrade the .sln file as it would normally.  The 2010 .sln file will be left untouched and you should be OK to do what you like with the 2013 solution.

Comment: Is there really no way to look at this solution outside of TFS? I don't want to update it, and I also don't want to make a second copy that is updated on TFS.

Comment: @NerdyFool Your only other option would be to open the .SLN file in something like Notepad and delete the source control bindings before opening it in VS.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that will work. This seems like a pretty obvious oversight on the part of Microsoft. I wonder why they don't allow looking at files without editing/checking out to edit.

Comment: You can open most files from source control explorer without needing to map them to a workspace or check them out. The problem is, when opening a solution file to 'look at it', VS is opening the solution which will then open projects and do the source control binding and all of that. If you just want to see the solution file itself, you have to either unload it in VS or edit it outside of VS.